# Using Slim and not render

Tags: php, render, slim

Currently, in my slim framework application I am using render from Slim views to display my websites but the render function is not running the php in my view files.

Looking at slim's documentation I found;
"The Slim application's render() method will echo() the output returned from the view object" which means the php is not be loaded but simply printed out on the client side.

My question is whether there is a different function in slim to load a page instead of simplying rendering it where its contents are echoed out.  I need the php on my pages to be ran, not simply printed.  I have provided an example below.

Code (*assume all routing is correct):

```
$app->render('home.php'); //in one file

//part of home.php that is not ran because it is simply echoed out
//i want this page to be loaded, not simply echoed out
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userLogin']))
    {
      echo '<form id="login" name="loginForm" method="post">
      <input class="loginForm" type="submit" value="Log In" id="submitLogin">
      <input class="loginForm" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="passLogin">
      <input class="loginForm" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="usernameLogin">
    </form>';
    }
    else
    {
      //echo 'button';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

slim framework has it's own [templates engine](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html)

why do you not use this feature ?